# What favour is suitable in return for running a costly software?

Tags: software

My work relies on using a software that is quite costly. It is painful to pay for a yearly license considering that I use it only a fraction of the time. Using an open-source software is an alternative, but the best available is not quite as good. So I was thinking of asking the favour of researchers in other institutions who have the license, to run the software. But what kind of favour would be suitable in return? A joint publication is an option, but running a software perhaps is not sufficient to warrant authorship. Also, sometimes the nature of the work precludes too deep involvement of other parties.

Comment: Are you yourself working in academia?

Comment: @dimpol, yes I am.

Comment: Could you strike a deal with a (few) different groups? For example: if you run software A on my data, I can run software B on your data. Or: if you pay for a license in even years, I will pay for one in odd years

Comment: The license might prohibit such use.

Comment: You may find someone that sell use of the software as a service (SAS).

Comment: Have you confirmed that there's no academic licensing? Is there a academic institution / site license that you could maybe convince the university to arrange?

Answer (score 4):

There are probably two important parameters for this question: (1) how close are you to the other party?, and (2) how long will it take the other party?

- *If you are good friends with the other party, and it will only take a few minutes* - probably no favor is needed, as long as you don't need this service all the time.
- *If you are good friends with the other party, and it will take hours or days to do* - in this case I would consider whether it is possible to set up the project in a way that co-authorship for the other party is legitimate. Yes, just running predefined scripts or doing some analyses that you have clearly laid out may not be enough to warrant co-authorship, but typically it's not a given that this is the *only* thing they do. Just get in touch with them early on in the project, and collaborate.
- *If you don't know the other party well or at all* - in this case, it seems unlikely that you will be able to convince them to run your software just as a favor, even if it does not objectively take much time. Your best bet is to get to know them better, and see if you can start a collaboration that will include, as part of the collaborative work, that they run the costly software for you.

*(of course, all of this assumes that the other party actually already has the software and using it for your purposes will not incur significant additional costs)*